# I want to make a search without database in Java by pulling the data database

Tags: java, database, button

I want to do a seamless search by pulling data from the database in java. I want to print the results as buttons. Can I do this? Could you give me a code sample?

Example :

https://i.hizliresim.com/POa33d.png

I need your help.

Comment: what is the meaning of "I want to print the results as buttons."? please explain your question in details

Comment: @AlokSingh i edited the questions

Comment: The subject of your question is very confusing. What do you mean by "without database ... by pulling the data database"? Also, what is a "seamless search"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JDBC for data search from database and result store in Result set like as below-

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("url", "root", "password");
    PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement("select * from tablename");
    ResultSet rs= ps.executeQuery();
```

and create dynamic button based on resultset data like

```
JFrame frm=new JFrame("My Frame");
    int y=20;
    while(cRs.next()){

        JButton jb=new JButton();
        jb.setText(rs.getString("colname"));
        frm.setBounds(30, y, 100, 30);
        y=y+35;
        frm.add(jb);
    }
```

Comment: how can i do search

Comment: by using select query

Comment: write the ode for search please

Comment: what is the search criteria?

Comment: if the text was deleted, changed or added.